# Converting a BoxStream into BoxFuture

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I have a function which returns a `BoxStream<(), io::Error>` and would like to convert this stream into a `Future` (or `BoxFuture`) but I'm having some compiler issues:

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::stream::BoxStream;
use std::io;

pub fn foo() -> BoxStream<(), io::Error> {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {
    let a = foo().into_future();
}
```

And the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `futures::Stream<Error=std::io::Error, Item=()> + std::marker::Send + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:23:19
   |
23 |     let a = foo().into_future();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `futures::Stream<Error=std::io::Error, Item=()> + std::marker::Send + 'static`
   |
   = note: `futures::Stream<Error=std::io::Error, Item=()> + std::marker::Send + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling [`futures::future::IntoFuture::into_future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.13/futures/future/trait.IntoFuture.html#tymethod.into_future), not [`futures::stream::Stream::into_future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.13/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.into_future). You need to import the trait:

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::Stream; // This
use futures::stream::BoxStream;
use std::io;

pub fn foo() -> BoxStream<(), io::Error> {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {
    let a = foo().into_future();
}
```

You can validate the difference with

```
fn main() {
    let a = futures::future::IntoFuture::into_future(foo());
    let a = futures::Stream::into_future(foo());
}
```